# Listing Rails API Data in Angular

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I and getting this exception:

```
Expected response to contain an array but got an object
```

coz
**isArray: true**
if ill make it false and ofcource this exception goes away.

```
{"themes":[{"id":1,"name":"This is first then","description":"This is first then"},{"id":2,"name":"Second Themes","description":"Second Themes"},{"id":3,"name":"This is $th theme","description":"This is $th theme"}]
}
```

But i don't know exactly how to retrieve data from this json.

```
<tr ng-show="themes.length" ng-repeat="theme in themes">
                <td>{{theme.name}}</td>
                <td>{{theme.description}}</td>
            </tr>
```

It displays nothing.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify your **json** response something like this:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"This is first then","description":"This is first then","created_at":"2014-10-08T10:37:08.208Z"},{"id":2,"name":"Second Themes","description":"Second Themes","created_at":"2014-10-08T11:28:54.900Z"},{"id":4,"name":"4th theme","description":"4th theme","created_at":"2014-10-09T05:13:35.605Z"}]
```

you can do it from your rails themes/index.json

```
object false
child(@themes => :themes) do
  extends "themes/show"
end
```

Modify it as :

```
object @themes
attributes :id, :name, :description, :created_at
```

and make `isArray: true` in your **Resource**

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.obj = {"themes":[{"id":1,"name":"This is first then","description":"This is first then"},{"id":2,"name":"Second Themes","description":"Second Themes"},{"id":3,"name":"This is $th theme","description":"This is $th theme"}]}

<tr ng-show="obj.themes.length > 0" ng-repeat="theme in obj.themes">
     <td>{{theme.name}}</td>
     <td>{{theme.description}}</td>
</tr>
```